# Ubuntu crontab not running all the time

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I wish someone could help me, I'm trying to use crontab to run some auto python scripts, and it works, but for some reason it won't run the scripts as expected.
If I don't make a SSH connection for to long the python scripts in the crontab won't run, if I log again they will run for some time after i log out and then they stop.

```
30 03 * * * systemctl reboot > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_reboot.log 2>&1
45 03 * * * sudo python /home/ajorge/server/python/startup.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_startup.log 2>&1
*/15 * * * * sudo python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_auth.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_auth.log 2>&1
*/15 * * * * sudo python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_characters.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_characters.log 2>&1
35 03 * * * sudo python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_world.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_world.log 2>&1
*/15 * * * * sudo python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_clean.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_clean.log 2>&1
```

The script is suppose to run every 15 min for the example below, but we can see that it didn't and there is a gap

[image]

If i make a SSH connection to the server it will start running the scripts again without me doint anything.

Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

Generate your crontab as user "root", then change them like:

```
30 03 * * * systemctl reboot > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_reboot.log 2>&1
45 03 * * * python /home/ajorge/server/python/startup.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_startup.log 2>&1
*/15 * * * * python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_auth.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_auth.log 2>&1
*/15 * * * * python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_characters.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_characters.log 2>&1
35 03 * * * python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_world.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_world.log 2>&1
*/15 * * * * python /home/ajorge/server/python/backup_clean.py > /home/ajorge/server/python/logs/crontab_clean.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Oh i didn't edited the crontab with root, let me try and i will let you know tomorrow :) every change i have a delay to check if it worked :(